# Downloading a file as attachment from a Django template is not working in firefox

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a Django view (**download-attachment**) which returns a django.http.response.HttpResponse object.

The dictionary representation of the object is:

```
{
    'reason_phrase': u'OK', 
    '_handler_class': None, 
    '_headers': {'content-length': ('Content-Length', '21'), 
                 'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                 'content-disposition': ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; 
    filename="upload_file.txt"')
                }, 
    '_charset': None, 
    '_closable_objects': [], 
    'cookies': <SimpleCookie: >, 
    'closed': False, 
    '_container': ['Upload to file\n']
}
```

In template the view is rendered on click of a hyperlink:

```
<a href="{% url "download-attachment" certificationID=certificationID fileID=attachment.id %}" download> {{attachment.name}}</a>
```

Here certificationID and fileID are parameters of the url for the download-attachment view.

In chrome, on clicking the hyperlink the file gets downloaded as an attachment with the filename given in Content-Disposition header of response.

In firefox, the file download fails. Need help in making the file download work in firefox.

Comment: It fails *how*? And what are you doing in Django to serve this content?

Comment: @DanielRoseman In Django, I am creating an object of django.http.response.HttpResponse class. And return that object from the view. 
`response = HttpResponse(data, content_type="text/plain")

response["Content-Description"] = "File Transfer"

response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"%s\"" % self.cweResponse.get("file_name")
            response['Content-Length'] = self.cweResponse.get("size")
return response`


In Firefox, the downloads list shows the filename with Failed and it can't be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a client or template issue. Firefox needs the Content-Encoding entity set in the header of the response for downloading file attachments. Even if there is no encoding the header needs to be set. Added Content-Encoding the Django HttpResponse object.

The new dictionary representation of the object is:

```
{
    'reason_phrase': u'OK', 
    '_handler_class': None, 
    '_headers': {'content-length': ('Content-Length', '21'), 
                 'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                 'content-encoding': ('Content-Encoding', 'None'),
                 'content-disposition': ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; 
    filename="upload_file.txt"')
                }, 
    '_charset': None, 
    '_closable_objects': [], 
    'cookies': <SimpleCookie: >, 
    'closed': False, 
    '_container': ['Upload to file\n']
}
```